# spring configuration import reference

Tags: spring, import, configuration

I've four spring configuration classes (annotated with @Configuration).
Configuration Class A defines beans which are to be used in Configuration classes B and C.
Configuration class D imports other three configuration classes A, B and C.

Class A

```
@Configuration
public Class A {

    @Bean
    public MyBean bean1() {
        return new Bean1();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean bean2() {
        return new Bean2();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean bean3() {
        return new Bean3();
    }

}
```

Class B

```
@Configuration
public class B {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean1")
    private MyBean bean1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean2")
    private MyBean bean2;

    @Bean
    public MyBeanCollector beanCollector() {
        MyBeanCollector mbc = new MyBeanCollector();
        mbc.add(bean1);
        mbc.add(bean2);
        return mbc;
    }

}
```

Class C

```
@Configuration
public class C {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean1")
    private MyBean bean1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean3")
    private MyBean bean3;

    @Bean
    public MyAnotherBeanCollector anotherBeanCollector() {
        MyAnotherBeanCollector mabc = new MyAnotherBeanCollector();
        mabc.add(bean1);
        mabc.add(bean3);
        return mabc;
    }

}
```

Class D

```
@Configuration
@Import(A.class, B.class, C.class)
public class D {
}
```

Now, my issue is, I keep on getting below exception on startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanCollector': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference? at         
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:327)
```

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error message. Please help.

Comment: Is this some university homework you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Created a [sample project](https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/spring-playground/releases/tag/so-33472688) with your config - works ok

1. git clone https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/spring-playground.git
2. cd spring-playground
3. git checkout so-33472688
4. ./gradlew -PmainClass=org.denis.test.spring.di.SpringStart execute

Comment: Thanks Denis. Any clue, when might the exception I am getting could be received. I've made sure that there are not cyclic dependencies in my code.

Comment: The code works just fine in the way you described it. Feel free to play around with that sample project to create a reproducible case. I'll take a look then